# Libgdx - Parallax background set horizontally, can't implement scrolling up and down

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I found a tutorial online to create a horizontally scrolling parallax background with this custom class:

```
public class ParallaxBackground extends Actor {

private float scroll;
private Array<Texture> layers;
private final int LAYER_SPEED_DIFFERENCE = 2;

float x, y, width, height, scaleX, scaleY;
float originX, originY, rotation;
float srcX, srcY;
boolean flipX, flipY;

private float speed;

public ParallaxBackground(Array<Texture> textures, HeroKnight player) {
    layers = textures;
    for(int i = 0; i <textures.size;i++){
        layers.get(i).setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat, Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat);
    }
    scroll = 0;
    speed = 0;

    x = y = originX = originY = rotation = 0;
    srcY = 0;
    width =  Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    scaleX = scaleY = 1;
    flipX = flipY = false;
}

public void setSpeed(float newSpeed){
    this.speed = newSpeed;
}

public void update(float deltaTime) {

}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.setColor(getColor().r, getColor().g, getColor().b, getColor().a * parentAlpha);

    scroll+=speed;
    srcX = scroll;
    batch.draw(layers.get(0), x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, (int)srcX, (int) srcY, layers.get(0).getWidth(), layers.get(0).getHeight(), flipX, flipY);
    for(int i = 1;i<layers.size;i++) {
        srcX = scroll + i*this.LAYER_SPEED_DIFFERENCE *scroll;
        batch.draw(layers.get(i), x, y, originX, originY, width, height,scaleX,scaleY,rotation,(int)srcX,(int)srcY,layers.get(i).getWidth(),layers.get(i).getHeight(),flipX,flipY);
    }
}
```

.

```
backgroundViewport = new ScreenViewport();
    stage = new Stage(backgroundViewport);

    Array<Texture> textures = new Array<Texture>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5;i++){
        textures.add(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/"+ i+".png")));
        textures.get(textures.size-1).setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat, Texture.TextureWrap.MirroredRepeat);
    }
parallaxBackground = new ParallaxBackground(textures, player);
    parallaxBackground.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    parallaxBackground.setSpeed(0);
    stage.addActor(parallaxBackground);
```

In the render method:

```
stage.act();
stage.draw();
```

Eveything works well when you are moving left to right. However, on my background image there is water down, so logically I want the screen to show it when the player is on the lower platforms, and make it scroll higher so that the water disappears when you go up.

So the question is: how do I make the blue part visible when the player is lower, and scroll it to the red part when you go higher?

[image]

Comment: Do you see how your paralax currently works for the X direction? You just need to duplicate the `scroll` and `speed` fields and give them different values for the Y direction, and apply them the same way you do with the X direction in your `draw()` method.

Comment: Yes, I tried your way, but the problem is that on the X axis the whole image is displayed and it scrolls based on a mirror. On the Y axis however I want only part of the image displayed and no wrapping, no mirrors, just moving the rendered part. I hope you get what I'm saying.

Comment: OK, I didn't see that was how you were doing the background. I understand, but I think the solution will be quite complicated.

Comment: I know. I figured that there's no way to do it with a camera as it would disrupt the horizontal scrolling and parallax. Still don't have any ideas.

Comment: You can shift the Y position of where the sprite is drawn. I just think trying to do this with an Actor in a Stage adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really manage to create a nice parallax without a Stage.